# Make select list output in alphabetical order in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, select

I have a select list in my model which lists a persons name with their employers name:

```
<li>Case Handler Name<span><%= f.select :person_id, Person.all.collect { |x| [x.name_and_company, x.id] } %></span></li>  

def name_and_company
return "#{personname} (#{company})"
end
```

Is it possible to force the select list to output in alphabetical order?

I am assuming I would put an order tag in there...somewhere?

```
(:order => 'personname DESC')
```

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
# controller
@people = Person.order_by('personname ASC').collect {|x| [x.name_and_company, x.id] }

# model
named_scope :order_by, lambda { |o| {:order => o} }  

# view
<%= f.select :person_id, @people %>
```

Comment: Hi J. If I am using the above in the Kase view, should it be in the people controller or the kase controller? Also, would the controller section of your code go within the def create block? Thanks.

Comment: If the view corresponds to a Kase's controller action, it should be in this same action on Kase's controller.

Answer (score 8):

Answer:

```
    #users_controller.rb
    def index
      @people = Person.alphabetically
    end

    #user.rb
    scope :alphabetically, order("name ASC")

    #index.haml
    = f.select :person_id, @people.all.collect { |p| [p.name, p.id] } %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Even easier ...

```
<%= f.select :name, options_from_collection_for_select(Person.order("name ASC"), :name, :name), :prompt => 'Select' %>
```

Note: Doesn't require custom methods or additions to controller